# ActiveModel Serializers two level attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

In my rails project, I have one serializer for user:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes ...
    has_one :project
    has_many :sessions
end
```

and one for session:

```
class SessionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes ...
    belongs_to :user
end
```

So if I return the session from any controller:

```
render json: session
```

I get something like:

```
{ "session": {
    "user: { ... }
    ...
}
```

but user does not contain the project, because it's too deep I guess, so how do I include that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure `default_includes` of `AMS` for deeper nesting

```
# config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.default_includes = '**'
```

Or you can try to provide `include` option to `render` method:

```
render json: session, include: ["user.project"]
```

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for the include solution.